# How to use createAsyncThunk from Redux Toolkit with TypeScript correctly?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, dispatch, redux-toolkit

I want to create a Redux slice for the users inside the project I work on. I have [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-glitter-ve35r?file=/src/MyButton.tsx) and I do not know why there is the following error on the `fetchAll` call in the `MyButton.tsx` file:

> fetchAll(arg: any): AsyncThunkAction<unknown, any, {}>
>
> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
>
> createAsyncThunk.d.ts(107, 118): An argument for 'arg' was not provided.

I have similar code in the project I work on and it does not have this error. I expected this to work just as it does in other similar files.

The relevant files from the sandbox:

## MyButton.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchAll } from "./redux/usersSlice";

export const MyButton = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        dispatch(fetchAll()); // I get an error on this fetchAll() call
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

## The definition of fetchAll

```
export const fetchAll = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/fetchAll",
  async (_: any, thunkAPI) => {
    const users = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(["a", "b", "c"]);
    });

    return users;
  }
);
```

## Update 1

If I call `fetchAll(null)` instead of `fetchAll()`, it works well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `void` type if you don't want that argument. `any` forces an argument.

```
export const fetchAll = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/fetchAll",
  async (_: void, thunkAPI) => {
    const users = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(["a", "b", "c"]);
    });

    return users;
  }
);
```

Comment: It works! Could you please explain how it works this way? I thought void is just a function return type. I read just the TS handbook. Thanks!

Comment: The RTK types are just geared to accept "void" for that. Have been since before I took over most of the type maintenance, so I just kept it at that pattern.

Answer (score 5):

And if you want to specify the types:

```
interface IThunkApi {
  dispatch: AppDispatch,
  state: IRootState,
}

export const fetchAll = createAsyncThunk<
string[], // return type
void, // args type
IThunkApi, // thunkAPI type
>("users/fetchAll", async (args, thunkAPI) => {
  const users = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(["a", "b", "c"]);
  });
   return users;
});
```