# How can I skip first argument to the payload creator of Redux Thunk using typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk, react-typescript

```
const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk<
  // Return type of the payload creator
  MyData,
  // First argument to the payload creator
  number,
  {
    // Optional fields for defining thunkApi field types
    dispatch: AppDispatch
    state: State
    extra: {
      jwt: string
    }
  }
>('users/fetchById', async (userId, thunkApi) => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users/${userId}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${thunkApi.extra.jwt}`,
    },
  })
  return (await response.json()) as MyData
})
```

This snippet is from redux-tooklit documentation.
Here I am going to use get request, so I won't have arguments passed. How can I skip the **first argument to the payload creator** *userId*

Comment: Isn't the first argument always required?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968873/how-to-use-createasyncthunk-from-redux-toolkit-with-typescript-correctly and https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/489

Comment: Thanks @Konrad for the links. It solved my issue or let's say confusion.

Answer (score 1):

so to avoid passing any unnecessary arguments we can simply just do it like this:

```
const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk<
  // Return type of the payload creator
  MyData,
  // First argument to the payload creator
  void, // pass void type here
  {
    // Optional fields for defining thunkApi field types
    dispatch: AppDispatch
    state: State
    extra: {
      jwt: string
    }
  }
>('users/fetchById', async (_, thunkApi) => { // pass underscore(_) here
  const response = await fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users/${userId}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${thunkApi.extra.jwt}`,
    },
  })
  return (await response.json()) as MyData
})
```